# flask application - Foreign key associated with column could not find table with which to generate a foreign key to target column

Tags: foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

Foreign key associated with column 'file.engine_software_version' could not find table 'engine_software' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'version_name'

```
 class EngineSoftwareModel(db.Model):
     __tablename__ = 'engine_software'


     version_name = db.Column(db.String(256), primary_key=True)
     version_identifier = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=True)


 class FileModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'file'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
               primary_key=True,
               index=True,
               autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    last_modified_utc = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    uploaded_utc = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    last_changed_utc = db.Column(db.DateTime)   
    engine_software_version = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(
                               'engine_software.version_name'),
                               nullable=True)
```

I've tried using the "__**table_name** __" still the same error.

Not able to recognize the table "engine_software".

i didn't find any other option, please help me out, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please cross check your table name whether it is a `engine_software` or `enginesoftware`

Comment: its engine_software @VenkatCh

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following lines assuming one-to-many relationship between the two tables. That's how the FileModel knows where to look.

```
from SQLAlchemy.orm import relationship
filemodels = relationship("FileModels", backref="engine_software")
```